# Riemann integrable function inequality

Tags: analysis

> Suppose that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. Then there exists a sequence $f_{k}$ of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ so that
>   $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty  }\int_{a}^{b}\left | f(x)-f_k(x) \right |dx=0 $$

(My attempt)
Suppose that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and for every sequence $f_{k}$ of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ , $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty  }\int_{a}^{b}\left | f(x)-f_k(x) \right |dx\neq 0 $.

I want to show contradiction. 
$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty  }\int_{a}^{b}\left | f(x)-f_k(x) \right |dx\neq 0 $ means that there exists $\epsilon > 0 $ such that for every $N$ ,

$n\geq N \Rightarrow    \int_{a}^{b}\left | f(x)-f_k(x) \right |dx  \geq \int_{a}^{b}\left (| f(x)|-|f_k(x) \right |)dx=\int_{a}^{b}\left | f(x) \right |dx-\int_{a}^{b}\left |f_k(x) \right |dx\geq \epsilon $

I don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2):

There is a step function $g_k$ s.t. $$\lim_{k\to \infty }\int_a^b |g_k-f|=0.$$
Set $$g_k(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n_k-1}a_i\boldsymbol 1_{[s_i,s_{i+1}[}$$ where
$$a=s_0<s_1<...<s_{n_k}=b.$$ 
Let $f_k$ the function that connect linearly all $(s_i,a_i)$. It's a continuous function s.t. $$\lim_{k\to \infty }\int_a^b |f_k-f|=0.$$

This is almost the [tropezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule).